# Cant visualize protected password portfolio elements

Tags: plugins, password

I'm using the "portfolio" plugin. After protecting an item with a password I can not see it, it appears as if it were hide to users.

Answer (score 0):

Password protected articles might be shown for logged-in users, especially certain level users such as administrator and editor.

Comment: Is it possible to show the elements with password protected to all users?

Comment: @DanielGB what do you mean 'the elements' ?

Comment: Id like to show, 'portfolios' (a plugin). It is literally, an image with a link to a gallery. This gallery is protected with password.